# Wolkenkit fails to start with "Error: Failed to get lowest processed position."

Tags: node.js, wolkenkit

I am currently looking into Wolkenkit by following the [tutorial to create a chat application](https://docs.wolkenkit.io/3.1.0/guides/creating-an-application-from-scratch/creating-the-write-model/).

After finishing writing the code and I ran `sudo yarn wolkenkit start`. This gave me the following error message:

```
Waiting for https://localhost:3000/ to reply...
(node:11226) Warning: Setting the NODE_TLS_REJECT_UNAUTHORIZED environment variable to '0' makes TLS connections and HTTPS requests insecure by disabling certificate verification.
Error: Failed to get lowest processed position.
  at EventSequencer.getLowestProcessedPosition (/wolkenkit/eventSequencer/EventSequencer.js:71:13)
  at /wolkenkit/app.js:63:41
  at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:68:7)

Application code caused runtime error.
✗ Failed to start the application.
```

A bit above the error the command warns about:

```
▻ Application certificate is self-signed.
```

I would appreciate any help on how to solve this and get the demo application to run on my local machine.

My development machine is running Debian GNU/Linux 10 with

- Node 13.8.0
- Yarn 1.21.1
- Docker 18.09.1
- Wolkenkit 3.1.2

Because of the warnings, I suspect this could be related to the X.509 certificate used for TLS. I created it using `openssl` like follows:

```
$ openssl req -new -sha256 -nodes -out localhost.csr -newkey rsa:2048 -keyout localhost.key -config <(
cat <<-EOF
[req]
default_bits = 2048
prompt = no
default_md = sha256
req_extensions = req_ext
distinguished_name = dn

[ dn ]
C=US
ST=New York
L=Rochester
O=Somthing
OU=Something Else
emailAddress=test@example.com
CN = localhost

[ req_ext ]
subjectAltName = @alt_names

[ alt_names ]
DNS.1 = localhost
EOF
)


$ openssl x509 -req -days 365 -in localhost.csr -signkey localhost.key -sha256 -out localhost.crt
```

Then I moved the localhost.crt and localhost.key into the following structure:

```
server/keys/localhost
├── certificate.pem
└── privateKey.pem
```

And set up a `package.json` like this:

```
{
    "name": "chat",
    "version": "0.0.0",
    "wolkenkit": {
        "application": "chat",
        "runtime": {
            "version": "3.1.0"
        },
        "environments": {
            "default": {
                "api": {
                    "address": {
                        "host": "localhost",
                        "port": 3000
                    },
                    "certificate": "/server/keys/localhost",
                    "allowAccessFrom": "*"
                },
                "fileStorage": {
                    "allowAccessFrom": "*"
                },
                "node": {
                    "environment": "development"
                }
            }
        }
    },
    "dependencies": {
        "wolkenkit": "^3.1.2"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like this could be the same problem described [here in this Github issue](https://github.com/thenativeweb/wolkenkit/issues/127).

> The problem is that due to a change in the start command, we now
>   assume that there must be a read model (which has not yet been
>   defined, if you follow the guide).
>
> If you simply ignore this error, and follow on, the next thing is to
>   define the read model. Once you have done that, you can successfully
>   run wolkenkit start.